# Focusing the Row to be added in Inline Mode

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I am trying to add a new row to the ASPxGridView in the inline mode. What I want is, when I click the 'New' button I want the new row that I am going to add, to have the focus, that is, the row should be highlighted. How can I accomplish this?

I have tried ASPxGridView1.FocusedRowIndex = -1; inside the InitNewRow event, but it doesn't highlight the row.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You want new row to have focus, first editor in that row to have focus or just highlight that row? Also, I suppose that by highlightning you mean that row should have the same color as selected rows? Like [here](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/Selection/AdvancedSelection.aspx)?

Comment: Have you tried setting the row as selected?  You could also modify the style of just that row using HtmlRowCreated or HtmlCellCreated events.

Answer (score 0):

This links might guide you :

```
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q260744.aspx

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q259550.aspx

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q356961
```